# React - Pass data from Axios req to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I'd like to pass data from an Axios req that is in a separate component to another component. I will explain more detailed with my code snippets.

In my **doorsLayout.js** I am making an Axios call to an address. And I am getting the data in **res**.

```
this.serverRequest = axios
  .get('http://blablabla/locks')
  .then(res => {
    // Rerender state
    this.setState({
      res,
      dataToDisplay: res.data.slice(0, numToDisplay || 5)
    })
  })
```

Then (in the same file) I am making a new component called **doorsItem.js** here:

```
const items = dataToDisplay.map(item => <DoorsItem item={item} />)
```

And inside of **DoorsItem** I am outputting the data from the Axios call:

```
    const DoorsItem = ({ item }) =>
      <Grid>
        <Row key={item._id} className="show-grid">
          <Col md={12}>

            <ul style={{ marginTop: '10px' }}>
              <li className="info-container">
                <h4 className="title-text-container">{item.address.street}</h4>
{/*etc etc*/}
```

So I can output all of the information that I got from the Axios call with `{item.helloStackOverflow}`. But in the same file I'd like to output other stuff too, but from a different Axios req.

```
    <DropdownButton
      title="Lägg till ny användare"
      id="bg-nested-dropdown"
    >
   <MenuItem eventKey="1" style={{ marginLeft: '500px' }}>
     {/*Different Axios data here!*/}
   </MenuItem>
   </DropdownButton>
```

And the data I want to output is found in this component: **users.js**

```
this.serverRequest = axios
  .get('http://blablabla/customers') <-- Just a different endpoint
  .then(res => {
    // Rerender state
    this.setState({
      res,
      dataToDisplay: res.data.slice(0, numToDisplay || 5),
    })
  })
```

And like in **doorsItem.js** I have the same type of layout in **userItem.js**:

```
const UsersItem = ({ item }) =>
  <Row
    key={item._id}
    className="show-grid"
    style={{ margin: '-15px 0 -15px 0' }}
  >
    <Col md={12}>
      <ul style={{ marginTop: '10px' }}>
        <li className="info-container">
          <div>
            <h5 className="title-text-container">{`${item.name} ${item.surname}`}</h5>
```

So here is my question. If I want to output the data from `'http://blablabla/customers'` in my `doorsItem` what's the easiest and "best" way to do so? Because I played around a little and when I'm clicking the dropdown I only see **one** name, because that name is associated with an ID. But I just want to have a dropdown with all of the names from  `'http://blablabla/customers'`.

Sorry if my question is messy! But thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you could do:

1. Make container component which handles all of the requests, and passes data as props to children components.
2. Introduce shared store object, like Redux or MobX does.

[quote:](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1287)

> Sometimes you'll want to move from Redux state to React state (when
>   storing something in Redux gets awkward) or the other way around (when
>   more components need to have access to some state that used to be
>   local).

Realize in which situation you are in.

PS. I choose to store request data most of the times in shared Redux object.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm not super sure how to go with shared Redux objects hehe.

Comment: If you are limited to React state then keep in mind that react has one-way data flow - which means if you want two components share the same data, they must have common ancestor which will pass that data to them. Should be helpful: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-4-identify-where-your-state-should-live